# Internet Wireless Connection not working on my laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a problem with my HP dv6 notebook with Windows 7 bought in August 2011.

Many many times since the past and even today, whenever I up my laptop and login, I am usually getting "Not connected - No connections are available" on the wireless connection status. (It's when I see a monitor icon with a wire that has a red X on the bottom right of it, on the right side of the taskbar.)

I looked at the HP Connection Manager several times in the past where the wireless connection is disabled by the Device Manager. I went there, but I found no warning icons on any of the network peripherals used. Even today, I don't see any warning signs on hardware needed for the connection.

The only way I can think of to solve this problem is to consistently restart my computer. But I have to do so many times that it takes a lot of time for my laptop to connect again to a saved network or have the wireless board working again. I'm now getting too furious about it, since I can't spend money on a new laptop nor send it for repairs.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Is it completely clean of viruses and malware?

Comment: I got Microsoft Security Essentials. It's always enabled, but I never gotten a warning message about viruses or malware. The first time this ever started was when the Login Screen wouldn't come up after waking up the laptop, so I had to do an improper shutdown by holding down the power button.

Comment: Simply put, I can't be sure. Like an antivirus itself cannot remove every single virus in a computer...

Answer (score 1):

Viruses, malware, rootkits, etc. can cause all kinds of problems. Without ensuring its clean, you could end up chasing your tail, per se. Once it's clean you can work on dealing with the any file corruption which might be causing this issue.

**Here are 3 things you can do which may resolve your issue.**

1. Run [SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/) or [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system.
2. Update your Antivirus software definitions and run a complete virus scan. An additional free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its all gone might be a good idea.
3. Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the [System File Check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833). When it is done, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are all valid points. If it is malmare, try removing it/reformatting. If it is an actual hardware issue in the board and you don't have money for full repairs/replacement, you may want to try getting a usb wirless card. [An example of one](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/wireless-n-usb-2-0-adapter/9144137.p;jsessionid=750D0B0FD727EB6054F054317A7D0F2E.bbolsp-app02-112?id=1218990495974&skuId=9144137&st=usb%20wireless&cp=1&lp=6). There are others out there varying in price and quality, but you get the idea... just suggesting a plan b. Out of sheer morbid curiosity, did you check the external wireless access control? (its usually a button or fn command on the keyboard).

Comment: It's always enabled. (technically, there are times when the laptop finally connects with the Wi-Fi routers or discovers them whenever I am close to them...) That doesn't answer my question, though.

Comment: Without actually looking through your computer for the problem myself, giving a direct answer to an issue with many possible causes is difficult. I was simply trying to offer a plan b in case it was directly hardware related. You comment about being close to the router clarified this A LOT, you may want to edit your post to add that directly. I mentioned the external control because it does follow most of the behavior you described, except it will never find networks in range. Have you checked device manager and reinstalled the driver? If it can connect at all then the notebook recognizes it.

Comment: A side note: if your unsure if it is a virus and don't want to go very far out of your way, i would advise you make an ubuntu live cd or usb and run it to see if you connect easier. If you do not connect then ubuntu either does not have your wireless driver or its definitely a hardware issue and your screwed. If you do connect to a network at close range by chance (in win) try staying connected and walking away to check for any sharp signal drop.

Comment: If you did not know by the way "always on technically" is wrong your fn+F12 enables and disables wireless from the keyboard. You could have hit it on accident, you did not give a straight answer.

Comment: Oh, no... I hate it whenever I get an answer where in reaction, I hurt myself. In all the restarts I had, the light for the wireless board was very light blue. I never tapped on it by accideny. It has to do with either Windows 7 or the wireless board itself that's causing the problem... (it was my thinking, not anyome else.)

Comment: Good luck, hope its a quick and inexpensive endeavor. Sorry I couldn't solve your problem outright like the first answer you received.